# Run celery task in the background of django app

Tags: celery

I'm trying to call a celery in another function in django views but the celery task is supposed to take so long to run so the views function doesn't return its result until the task celery finish and i need the views function to return immediately while the task celery runs in the background.
I don't have any idea how to do so or if there are any other solutions except celery that i can use.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To enable task scheduling and make sure the function could return a response and leave the long duration process running at the background, I suggest you use [Django Background Tasks repo](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks).

Check out the documentation [here](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).